# How to verify if the first character in a string is letter or number?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Only account queries, complaints and suggestions with a valid account numbers will be processed, Write a subprogram called `ValidateAccNum` to receive an account number as a string indicating weather it is valid or not. A valid account number must satisfy the following criteria:

- The account number must have only SEVEN characters.
- The account number must start with a letter.

The problem I am having is figuring out if the first character of the account number is a string or integer. Heres my code:

```
procedure TfrmQuestion3.ValidateAccNum(AccNum: string);
var
  RealACCNum : Boolean;
  ACCNumLength : Integer;
  StartACCNum : string;
begin
  RealACCNum := False;
  ACCNumLength := Length(AccNum);
  StartACCNum := AccNum[1];

  If (ACCNumLength = 7) and (StartACCNum = string) // <--- This is obviously the 
                                                   //      problem, I know its wrong
    then RealACCNum = True
    else exit;
  end;
```

So how do I check weather its a String character or an Integer?

Comment: `if (Length(AccNum) = 7) and IsCharAlpha(AccNum[1]) then...` (for Delphi 7)

Comment: Small sidenote, you forgot to check if the other 6 characters represent a number...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (Length(AccNum) = 7) and IsCharAlpha(AccNum[1]) then
```

You can check like that ^
                                      |

Comment: So there weren't any use for those variables? (`ACCNumLength` and `StartACCNum`)

Comment: Btw,it's a good idea to get into the habit of checking whether a string is empty before trying to access any of its characters using [].  What is MyString[1] supposed to return if MyString is empty?  In the answer, the check on Length() does that of course, but there was none in your q.